# read(byte [] b) of InputStream return a byte array has negative element

Tags: java

My program read a file into byte array, but I don't know why there are many negative number in array result. I think element in array has value in the range 0 to 255. Code here:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File("C:\\1.mp3");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fis.read(bytes);
            boolean check = true;
            int i = -1;
            while(check)
            {
                i=i+1;
                if(bytes[i]<0)
                {
                    check = false;
                    System.out.println("There is a negative number.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: Java bytes are values in the range -128 to 127. I don't see why that is a problem.

Comment: But I read Java Document, I see "Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255". I think 0 <= array element <= 255.

Comment: That is only true if you read one byte at a time as an `int` using `int read()` Using this function you get a 0 to 255 value and -1 if you have reached the end of the stream.

Answer (score 8):

A Java `byte` has range -128 to 127.  See [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java tutorial for more info.

You are confused between two ways of reading bytes from an `InputStream`.

The first way is to use the [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) method to read one byte at a time.  This method returns an `int` (not a `byte`) that has either the value read (range 0-255) or a -1 to indicate the end of the stream has been reached.  The `int` type is a signed 32-bit value in Java.

The second way is what has been done in the example code, using [InputStream.read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) to read many bytes at once.  This method takes a `byte` array as a parameter, and returns an `int` indicating the number of bytes read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.  These `byte` values will have range -128 to 127 since the `byte` type is a signed 8-bit value in Java.

If you need unsigned values from the second way, you can convert by performing the following:

```
byte b = ...; //element in the byte array read from stream
int i = b & 0xFF;
```

This sets the lower 8 bits of a 32-bit `int` with the value from the `byte` value, giving you an unsigned value.

Comment: Thank @prunge very much, I have new question. I use FileOutputStream.write(int b) to write data to text file. I know it use ASCII table, such as if b = 57, it will write 9 to text file, if I use b it out range of ASCII(1 - 127), I want to know Java how to process?

Comment: @loithuxua `FileOutputStream` will use the lowest 8 bits of the `int` value passed into `write()`.  If writing characters, I would suggest using `Writer`s instead of `OutputStream`s as they are designed to deal with character encoding and multibyte characters.